# React component not refresh after search active

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

i have an error in my react code, my result component is not changed after change array data, in console i just see new arrays after change input, new builded data is work, but component result isnot changed.

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import Header from './Header'
import Content from './Content'
import Footer from './Footer'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        stripdata: null,
        query: ""
      }
      this.query = this.query.bind(this)
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/info.json`)
              .then(results => results.json())
              .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    stripdata: data
                })
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log("Didn't connect to API", err)
              })
    }
    query(e) {
        e = e.trim().toLowerCase();
        this.setState({
            query: e
        })
    }
    show(data, query) {
        return (query.length > 0) ? 
                    data.filter(item => { return item.fakename.stripclub.toLowerCase().match( query ) }) :
                    data
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.show(this.state.stripdata, this.state.query))
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header onQuery={this.query}/>
            {   
                (this.state.stripdata === null) ?
                    <div className="loading">Loading data...</div> :
                    <Content onResult={ this.show(this.state.stripdata, this.state.query) }/>
            }
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Content.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Result from './Result'

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        stripdata: this.props.onResult
      };
    }
    componentWillMount() {

    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="Content">
            <Result stripdata={ this.state.stripdata }/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Finder.jsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class Finder extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {}
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        }

        handleChange(e) {
            this.props.find(e.target.value)
        }

        render() {
            return (
              <div className="Finder">
                <form id="search" onSubmit="">
                  <span>i want</span> 
                    <input  type="text"
                          placeholder="type who you want"
                          onChange={ this.handleChange }
                  />
                </form>
              </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Finder;
```

Header.jsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Finder from './Finder'

    class Header extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        };
        this.find = this.find.bind(this);
      }
      find(e) {
        this.props.onQuery(e)
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="Header">
            <div className="inner">
                <h2>Find with which girl you want to spend your time !!!</h2>
                <Finder find={ this.find }/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Header;
```

Result.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PersonCard from './PersonCard'

class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        stripdata: this.props.stripdata
      };
    }
    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="result">
          {
            this.state.stripdata.map((item, i) => {
                return <PersonCard key={i} data={item}/>
            })
          }
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Result;

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Facebook from 'react-icons/lib/fa/facebook'
import VK from 'react-icons/lib/fa/vk'
import Phone from 'react-icons/lib/fa/phone'
```

PersonCard.jsx

```
class PersonCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        info: this.props.data
      };
    }
    render() {
        var now = new Date().getFullYear();
        return (
            <div className="PersonCard">
                <div className="layer one">
                    <div className="side left face-image">
                        <img src={(this.state.info.photo) ? this.state.info.photo : ""} alt="Person Pic" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="side right info">
                        <p><b>Fake Name:</b> { this.state.info.fakename.stripclub }</p>
                        <p><b>Real Name:</b> { (this.state.info.name) ? this.state.info.name : null }</p>
                        <p><b>Currently Workplace:</b> { (this.state.info.address.work ) ? this.state.info.address.work : null }</p>
                        <p><b>Age:</b> { (this.state.info.born) ? (now - this.state.info.born.slice(0, 4)) : null }</p>
                        <p><br /><a href={ (this.state.info.fakename.facebook) ? this.state.info.fakename.facebook.id : null } ><icon><Facebook /></icon> { (this.state.info.fakename.facebook) ? this.state.info.fakename.facebook.user : null }</a></p>
                        <p><br /><a href={ (this.state.info.fakename.vk) ? this.state.info.fakename.vk.id : null }><icon><VK /></icon> { (this.state.info.fakename.vk) ? this.state.info.fakename.vk.user : null }</a></p>
                        <p><br /><a href={ (this.state.info.phone) ? "tel:" + this.state.info.phone : null }><icon><Phone /></icon> { (this.state.info.phone) ? this.state.info.phone : null }</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="layer two">
                    <div className="about">
                        <p>{ this.state.info.physical }</p>
                        <p>{ (this.state.info.work_days) ? 'All Week ' + this.state.info.work_days : null }</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PersonCard;
```

Please help me with with this issue.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write the Content component like this:

```
class Content extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="Content">
            <Result stripdata={  this.props.onResult }/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the Result component like this also:

```
class Result extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="result">
          {
             this.props.stripdata.map((item, i) => {
                return <PersonCard key={i} data={item}/>
            })
          }
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And in the PersonCard replace every reference of this.state to this.props and remove the assignment in the constructor.

I am guessing the problem is with the assignments of props into state like in the Content component:

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        stripdata: this.props.onResult
      };
    }
```

the constructor is probably not getting called after the input values changes.
The assumption that the constructor is getting called every time the component is rendered confuses a lot of beginner react devs...

Anyway you dont need to use state in these presentational components (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

just use props.

Comment: please provide the Result component also

Comment: implemented, tnx